# What's the difference between 消える and 消え失せる?

Tags: word-choice

In what situations would you use 消え失せる instead of 消える, and 消える instead of 消え失せる?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

消え失せる is a compounded verb of 消える "disappear" + 失せる "be lost". You can reword it as 消えてなくなる.

消える only implies it disappears from your presence, or somewhere you can easy see. 失せる means it's gone and becomes irretrievable (it's not a common word today except when you say 失せろ！ "Get lost!").

So, detectives can search after 消えた財宝 "missing treasures", because it must be still hidden in somewhere, but not 消え失せた財宝, because none of them remains anymore.